# How to I set what browser Adobe Reader uses to open links?

Tags: windows-xp, browser, adobe-reader

I have a Windows XP computer with Chrome set as the default browser. However whenever I click a link embedded in a pdf document I'm viewing with Adobe Reader 8.2.1 I get a popup security warning asking if this is ok, and then the Reader opens the link in IE.

Is there a way to change Adobe Readers default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that URL links from within Adobe Reader always launch Internet Explorer instead of the default browser, say Firefox, seems be a common problem from within the Reader, and from within the Help (Google "Adobe Reader default browser").

Last year Adobe's own tech note declared it "a rare problem and there is no known solution":
http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_15579
and the problems continue in relation to Vista [HTML links don't open in default web browser on Windows Vista (Adobe AIR)]:
http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=kb403122

It also seems to have been a problem for long time going back to early versions of Mozilla Firefox 1.06. Various other forums too suggest that it's just a matter of using Start | Set Program Access and Defaults, and choosing "Use default browser" or forcing Firefox to be the default. 
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t219716-adobe-reader-6.html
Like contributors here, I found that neither method worked.

Note that Mozilla's own useful KB article:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Default_browser#Force_Firefox_to_make_itself_the_default
suggests you set individual file types to default to FireFox, but I had already had those set anyway.

The solution I chose to make URL links in PDFs trigger my Firefox browser reliably was to dump Adobe Reader and install the faster and smaller Foxit Reader (http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/rd_intro.php). The only change you have to make inside Foxit is to tick the "Create links from URLs" tickbox under Edit | Preferences | General.

Source: http://www.acrobatusers.com/forums/aucbb/viewtopic.php?id=7931

Comment: TL;DR No, use Foxit Reader instead.

Answer (score 8):

**[Acrobat User Community Forums](http://www.acrobatusers.com/forums/aucbb/viewtopic.php?id=7931)** exactly cover that issue. Sergiy Byelozyorov's answer is, in fact, the exact copy of the answer of *paulc* in the relevant thread. I recommend you to read the full thread for the whole story.

However, since the thread is old (the latest message was on June 2008), it may be worthwhile to check Adobe Reader's `Edit > Preferences > Internet > Internet Settings > Programs > Default web browser` menu to see if it is possible to change default browser on version 8.2.1. If you can't, then **[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/)** is a good substitute for Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes, indeed I copied an answer from there. Sorry, I forgot to add source to my answer this time. I typically do that whenever I am citing some other web-site.

Comment: This answer works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older thread, but one solution I have enjoyed is just setting the default application to open PDF files in Windows to Chrome.

Control Panel > Folder Options > File Types > Scroll down to Extension "PDF" > Click "Change" > Click "Select Application From A List" > Select "Google Chrome"

Now, conceivably, once you got to the PDF Extension in the File Types tab, you **could** click Advanced, then click Edit "open" action (or Create, if the "open" action doesn't exist) and in "Application used to perform action" field, put " --focus-on-existing-tab-on-open=false %1"

This way, if you don't have Chrome running, but you have a bunch of existing tabs when it does come up, it doesn't replace an existing tab, but rather opens the PDF in another new tab.

Hope that helps.